# Find the critical point of the following function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-derivative

Let $f(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{2}x^2+cos(y)$

I want to find its critical points:

- $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta x} = x$
- $\dfrac{\delta f}{\delta y} =-sin(y)$

Now I have to solve the following system: 
$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        x = 0  \\
        -sin(y) = 0
    \end{array}
\right.$

Comment: If $ \ x \ $ and $ \ y \ $ are independent variables in the function, they do not belong in each other's partial derivatives... Also, is it specified that the value of $ \ y \ $ is limited to the "principal circle"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to calculate the partial derivatives correctly:

$$
f_x = x,
$$

and

$$
f_y = -\sin y.
$$

Setting these equal to 0, we get that the $x$ coordinate must be $0$, and the $y$ coordinate is $n\pi$, where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ is any integer. So there are infinitely many critical points, all of the form $(0, n\pi)$.

Answer (score 3):

You did the partial derivatives wrong. It's actually $\begin{cases}f_x=x=0\\f_y=-sin(y)=0\end{cases}$